# What will be the running time of merging k sorted length n arrays?

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

Let's assume I want k sorted length-n arrays into a single sorted length-kn array. Consider the algorithm that first divides the k arrays into k/2 pairs of arrays, and uses the Merge subroutine to combine each pair, resulting in k/2 sorted length-2n arrays. The algorithm repeats this step until there is only one length-kn sorted array.

My question is what will be the running time of this procedure, as a function of k and n, ignoring constant factors and lower-order
terms?

Comment: What is running time for every stage? How many stages?

Comment: Time Complexity would be `O(k*n*log k)`.

Comment: @SanketMakani, Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @3iL Well, You can relate it with `Classic MergeSort` for array having `n` elements. In that case, total levels would be `log n` and total number of elements to be processed on each level would be `n`. Here we have total `log k` levels and we need to process all the elements on each of the level which is `k*n`. So total complexity would be `O(k*n*log k)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first merge pass iteration deal with the k/2 array of length n pair each taking time proportional to 2n, so it takes Θ(nk) time.

The second merge pass iteration deal with a k/4 array of length 2n pair each taking time proportional to 4n, so it also takes Θ(nk) time.

since we need only log<sub>2</sub>k merge passes, we obtain the running time of Θ(nklogk).